# Rails: Images on one server, CSS and Javascript on another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a rails app that has a bunch (hundreds) of images that are hosted on an S3 server. To have helpers like image_tag point here I had to add this to by config/environments/development.rb test.rb and production.rb:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

However, this also means that it looks there for CSS and Javascript. This is a huge pain because each time I change the CSS I have to re-upload it to Amazon.

So.. Is there an easy way I can make my app look to Amazon for images, but locally for CSS/Javascript?

(I'm using Rails 3.0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a `Proc` object to `config.action_controller.asset_host` and have it determine the result programmatically at runtime.

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new do |source|
  case source
  when /^\/(images|videos|audios)/
    "http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com"
  else
    "http://mydomain.com"
  end
end
```

but left as it is, this would give you `http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/images/whatever.png` when you use `image_tag :whatever`.

If you want to modify the path as well, you can do something very similar with `config.action_controller.asset_path`

```
config.action_controller.asset_path = Proc.new do |path|
  path.sub /^\/(images|videos|audios)/, ""
end
```

which would give you `http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/whatever.png` combined with the former.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping you from passing full url to `image_tag`:  `image_tag("#{IMAGE_ROOT}/icon.png")`.

But to me moving static images (icons, backgrounds, etc) to S3 and leaving stylesheets/js files on rails sounds kinda inconsistent.  You could either move them all to S3 or setup Apache for caching (if you're afraid users pulling big images will create too much overhead for Rails).

BTW, you don't have to put `config.action_controller...` into config files for all three environments: placing that line just in `config/environment.rb` will have the same effect.

Comment: I thought about doing IMAGE_ROOT but it doesn't seem very DRY. And having the css locally is just for development. Eventually they would all be on S3

Comment: @pieri434 Why don't you have both images and stylesheets locally for development, then? Amazon S3 console should allow you to export images easily.